# Mathematica gives the wrong answer if I define a variable "too late"

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I have the functions

```
Sol[m_] = (1/(r Gamma[1 - n]))
  E^(-(n/r)) (r/n)^
   m Gamma[1 + 
     m] ((E^(n/r) r + n ExpIntegralE[n, -(n/r)]) Gamma[1 + m - n] + 
     n^2 (-(n/r))^m ExpIntegralE[-m + n, -(n/r)] Gamma[-n]);
```

and

```
Sol2[m_] = 
  1/(2 r) (r/n)^
   m Gamma[1 + m] (-(1/Gamma[1 - n]) 2 r^2 Gamma[1 + m - n] \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(K[1] = 0\), \(\(-1\) + m\)]\(\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-
\*FractionBox[\(2\ n\), \(r\)]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\))\), \(n - K[1]\)]\ \((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(4\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\))\), \(K[1]\)]\ ExpIntegralE[\(-1\) + 
               n - K[1], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[\(-n\)]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[
              2 - n + K[1]]\ Gamma[1 - n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n/r\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[1 - n]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[2 - n + K[1]]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[1 - n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)] + n\ r\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ Gamma[1 - n]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[2 - n + K[1]]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[1 - n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(5\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\))\), \(K[1]\)]\ ExpIntegralE[\(-1\) + 
               n - K[1], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[\(-n\)]\), \(3\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[1], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)] - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n/r\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[1 - n]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[1]]\ Gamma[
              2 - n + K[1], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)] - n\ r\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[1 - n]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[1]]\ Gamma[
              2 - n + K[1], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)])\))\)/\((n\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Gamma[1 - n]\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[
           2 - n + K[1]]\ \((2 + K[1])\))\)\)\) + 
     1/(n^2 Gamma[-n])
       2 E^(-(n/
       r)) (ExpIntegralE[n, -(n/r)] Gamma[1 + m - n] + 
        n (-(n/r))^
         m ExpIntegralE[-m + n, -(n/r)] Gamma[-n]) (-n^2 + (-2 + 
           n) (-1 + n) r^3 \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(K[2] = 0\), \(\(-1\) + m\)]\(\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ n\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\))\), \(-K[2]\)]\ \((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\))\), \(K[2]\)]\ ExpIntegralE[\(-1\) + 
                  n - K[2], \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ Gamma[3 - n] + 2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n/r\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] - 3\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n/r\)]\ n\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n/r\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] + 
               2\ n\ r\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] - 3\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ r\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(3\)]\ r\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-
\*FractionBox[\(n\), \(r\)]\)]\ Gamma[
                 2 - n + K[2]])\))\)/\((\((\(-2\) + n)\)\ \((\(-1\) + 
               n)\)\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(r\), \(4\)]\ Gamma[3 - n]\ \((2 + K[2])\))\)\)\)));
```

I am interested in the value of

```
A = FullSimplify[-(FullSimplify[Sol[n]]/FullSimplify[Sol2[n]])];
```

To make it a bit more simple, I am for now just interested in the case

```
r = 1;
```

Now if I immediately define

```
n = 2.01
```

and after that define A as above, I find

```
Re[A]
```

as

```
-0.572922
```

Since the exact answer for n approaching 2 should be $-\frac{4}{7}$, this is probably the correct answer. However, if I now write

```
Clear[n]
```

and again define A as above, I get that A is equal to

```
    -((E^n n^2 ((-n)^n + (1 + E^-n n ExpIntegralE[n, -n])/
       Gamma[1 - n]) Gamma[-n])/((ExpIntegralE[n, -n] - 
       E^n (-n)^n Gamma[-n]) (-n^2 + (-2 + n) (-1 + n) \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(K[2] = 0\), \(\(-1\) + n\)]\(\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-n\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-n\))\), \(-K[2]\)]\ n\ \((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-n\))\), \(K[2]\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ ExpIntegralE[\(-1\) + n - 
                 K[2], \(-n\)]\ Gamma[3 - n] + 2\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] - 3\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n\)]\ n\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(n\)]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] + 
              2\ n\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-n\)]\ Gamma[2 - n + K[2]] - 
              3\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(2\)]\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-n\)]\ Gamma[
                2 - n + K[2]] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(n\), \(3\)]\ ExpIntegralE[n, \(-n\)]\ Gamma[
                2 - n + K[2]])\))\)/\((\((\(-2\) + n)\)\ \((\(-1\) + 
              n)\)\ Gamma[3 - n]\ \((2 + K[2])\))\)\)\))))
```

Now something weird is going on, since if I now define

```
n = 2.01
```

and compute Re[A], it is suddenly equal to

```
-0.480325
```

I would like my value A as function of n, but when I clear n and then define Afun[n_] = Re[A] and compute values of Afun, I am now naturally getting the wrong answers (like Afun[2.01] = -0.480325). My question is if there is any explanation for this, and more specifically how I would be able to get a correct function for my value A in terms of n.

Comment: If you define a function you might want to use := instead of =. In your case you probably also want to use sol[ n_, r_ ] := ..., so that you don't run into trouble when redefining r.

Comment: Thank you @Gert, makes sense. I am still curious as to why my initial approach gave wrong answers, but I followed your advice and I have indeed gotten a function which gives the correct solution.